# Downloading and replacing file in package

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

In my Visual Studio 2013 Solution, I added a folder "mAppData" with some static Content for the app.
One of the files is a Textfile ("imprint.txt").

On a phone page, I Display the content of this file. This works fine.

Is there a way to replace this file on runtime? I want to download new Content from web and replace this file with the downloaded content.

Answer (score 0):

rather than downloading and replacing the "imprint.txt" you could simply download the imprint as text (from your imprint.txt - stored online) and display it:

```
    var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, args) => MessageBox.Show("downloaded imporint: " + args.Result);
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://yourSite.ch/imprint.txt"));
```

My sample simply shows a MessageBox with the downloaded text. However, you can update a text control or similar.

If you want the content to be available even if you are temporary offline, you can store the file  in the filestorage.
Consider adding multiple files for different languages in your build and load the file depending on the localization of your phone.

However - replacing a existing file for your Solution is not allowed on runtime. Consider this as a safety feature. If the Codebase of your app could change during runtime, your code would be injectable by an attacker.

Comment: In Germany, the imprint must be available under all situations ... even if no Network is present. Therefore I want to have a text file in my Project Folder and the ability to Change it´s Content if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't alter the package content at runtime, it is read-only.

The place where you can store data locally is the Isolated Storage. What you should do is create a file in the Isolated Storage at first launch that stores the original content of your file ("imprint.txt") and then you'll be able to change it any time you want.

Here is a tutorial that explains how to read and write text in the Isolated Storage: [All about WP7 Isolated Storage - Read and Save Text files](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-read-and-save-text-files)